# Is there a prefered method of creating hot-spots on images using Tridion?

Tags: image, methods, tridion

Each hotspot point will be tied to a list of components that gets displayed when we hover over the hotspot.

Comment: Are you describing ImageMaps? I am not clear what you mean by hotspots?

Comment: Method depends on who needs to control what and your preferred output (image maps, multiple images, etc), but you'll likely have a set of schema fields for some type of author. Components make sense *in* the Content Manager Explorer, but components alone don't display on your site, they're either Component Presentations or part of one.

Comment: Chris,When I said hotspots, I meant image maps. Alvin, the content editors like to have the control of what needs to be displayed on the hotsopt. So we let the editiors pick the components. We then have to publish those using a CT

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by hotspot, but I once wrote an imagemap tool for SDL Tridion (http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/image-map-extension-for-sdl-tridion) - could be this be related to what you're looking for?  It could quite easily be extended to allow component linking.